# How can I do a color or numeric replacement with bitwise/boolean logic

Tags: c#, winforms, image, boolean-logic

How can I do a color replace like the code below without using the if statement and instead use boolean algebra (or some other magic that will not introduce conditional logic)

The Problem (excuse the code):

```
private Image ReplaceRectangleColors(Bitmap b, 
                                     Rectangle rect, 
                                     Color oldColor, 
                                     Color newColor)
    {
        BitmapData bmData = b.LockBits(rect, 
                                       ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                                       PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        int stride = bmData.Stride;
        IntPtr Scan0 = bmData.Scan0;

        byte red = 0;
        byte blue = 0;
        byte green = 0;

        unsafe
        {
            byte * p = (byte *)(void *)Scan0;
            int nOffset = stride - rect.Width *3; 

            for(int y=0; y < rect.Height; ++y)
            {
                for(int x=0; x < rect.Width; ++x )
                {
                    red = p[0];
                    blue = p[1];
                    green = p[2];

                    if (red == oldColor.R 
                        && blue == oldColor.B 
                        && green == oldColor.G)
                    {
                        p[0] = newColor.R;
                        p[1] = newColor.B;
                        p[2] = newColor.G;
                    }

                    p += 3;
                }
                p += nOffset;
            }
        }

        b.UnlockBits(bmData);

        return (Image)b;
    }
```

The problem I have is that if the image is huge this code gets executed many times and has poor formance. I know there has to be a way to substitute the color replacement with something much cleaner/faster. Any ideas?

Just to summarize and simplify, I want to turn
    if (red == oldColor.R 
        && blue == oldColor.B 
        && green == oldColor.G)
    {
       red = newColor.R;
       blue = newColor.B;
       green = newColor.G;
    }

into a bit operation that doesn't include an if statement.

Comment: Two things: as the now-deleted previous comment said, this code never actually modifies the bitmap, it’s a no-op. Secondly, even if you rewrite the code to use bit operations this doesn’t necessarily mean that it’s faster. What I would rather do is replace the three colour equality tests by a single test by treating the  24 bit colour value as an integer instead of as three separate bytes.

Comment: Yeah, the code is not complete as is. I figure if I'm looking at a small 800x600 image my array size is ~1.4M and calling an if statement 1.4M times for each instance on my form this could be quite slow.

Comment: You sure about that?  What are the numbers?  Don't "figure", test it.  If it accounts for some tiny fraction of the CPU time and the operation is plenty fast enough then it is a waste of time, move on.

Comment: That said, if the image were 32bpp you could cast the `byte*` to an `int*` and compare that value instead.

Comment: @EdS. You're right, I am running some tests right now. We'll see how it goes.

Comment: Note that `LockBits` ends up calling the `GetDIBits`API function, which actually copies the bits to a memory buffer. And `UnlockBits` calls `SetDIBits`, which copies them back. That's a significant amount of processing, and might very well dwarf the amount of time spent in your loop. You should time your code (in release mode, without the debugger attached) to see exactly how much time your loop is taking, which will give you an idea of what your potential savings is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't any bitwise operations that will replace pixels of one colour with another for you. In fact, reading a pixel, applying a bitwise operation and writing back the results *for every pixel* will probably work out slower than reading a pixel and only doing any work on it and writing it back if it matches your target colour.

However, there are some things that can be done to speed up the code, with increasing levels of complexity:

1) The first thing you could do is not to read the 3 bytes before you do the compare. If you read each byte only as it is needed for the comparison, then in the case that the red byte doesn't match, there isn't any need to read or compare the Green/Blue bytes. (The optimiser may well work this out on your behalf though)

2) Use cache coherence by accessing the data in the address-order that it is stored in. (You're doing this by working on the scanlines by putting x in your inner loop).

3) Use multithreading. Break the image into (e.g.) 4 strips, and process them in parallel, and you should be able to get a "several times" speedup if you have a 4+ core processor.

4) You may be able to work several times faster by using a 32-bit or 64-bit value instead of four or eight 8-bit values. This is because fetching one byte from memory might take a similar time (give or take some cache coherence etc) to fetching an entire CPU register (4 or 8 bytes). Once you have the value in a register, you can do a single comparison (RGBA) rather than four (R, G, B, A bytes separately), and then a single write back - potentially as much as 4x faster. This is the easy case (for 32-bpp images), as they conveniently fit one-pixel-per-int, so you can use a 32-bit integer to read/compare/write an entire RGBA pixel in a single operation.

But for other image depths you will have a much harder case, as the number of bytes in each pixel will not exactly match the size of your 32-bit int. For example, for 24bpp images, you will need to read three 32-bit dwords (12 bytes) so that you can then process four pixels (3 bytes x 4 = 12) on each iteration of your loop. You will need to use bitwise operations to peel apart these 3 ints and compare them to your 'oldcolour' (see below). An added complication is that you must be careful not to run off the end of each scanline if you are processing it in 4-pixel jumps. A similar process applies to using 64-bit longs, or processing lower bpp images - but you will have to start doing more intricate bit-wise operations to pull the data out cleanly, and it can get pretty complicated.

So how do you compare the pixels?

The first pixel is easy.

```
int oldColour = 0x00112233;    // e.g. R=33, G=22, B=11
int newColour = 0x00445566;

int chunk1 = scanline[i];      // Treating scanline as an array of int, read 3 ints (12 bytes)
int chunk2 = scanline[i+1];    // We cache them in ints as we will read/write several times
int chunk3 = scanline[i+2];

if (chunk1 & 0x00ffffff == oldColour)              // read and check 3 bytes of pixel
    chunk2 = (chunk2 & 0xff000000) | newColour;    // Write back 3 bytes of pixel
```

The next pixel has one byte in the first int, and 2 bytes in the next int:

```
if ((chunk1 >> 24) == (oldColour & 0xff))    // Does B byte match?
{
    if ((chunk2 & 0x0000ffff) == (oldColour >> 8))
    {
        chunk1 = (chunk1 & 0x00ffffff) | (newColour & 0xff);   // Replace B byte in chunk1
        chunk2 = (chunk2 & 0xffff0000) | (newColour >> 8);     // Replace G, B bytes in chunk2
    }
}
```

Then the third pixel has 2 bytes (RG) in chunk2 and 1 byte (B) in chunk3:

```
if ((chunk2 >> 16) == (oldColour & 0xffff))
{
    if ((chunk3 & 0xff) == (oldColour >> 16))
    {
        chunk2 = (chunk2 & 0x0000ffff) | (newColour << 16);  // Replace RG bytes in chunk2
        chunk3 = (chunk3 & 0xffffff00) | (newColour >> 16);  // Replace B byte in chunk3
    }
}
```

And finally, the last 3 bytes in chunk3 are the last pixel

```
if ((chunk3 >> 8) == oldCOlour)
    chunk3 = (chunk3 & 0x000000ff) | (newColour << 8);
```

... and then write back the chunks to the scanline buffer.

That's the gist of it (and my masking/combining above may have some bugs, as I wrote the example code quickly and may have mixed up some of the pixels!).

Of course, once it works, you can then optimise it a load more - for example, whenever I compare stuff to parts of the oldColour (e.g. `oldColour >> 16`), I can precaclulate that constant outside the entire processing loop, and just use an "oldColourShiftedRight16" variable to avoid recalculating it on every pass through the loop. THe same goes for all the bits of newColour that are used. Potentially you may be able to make some gains by avoiding writing back the values that haven't been touched, too, as many of your pixels probably won't match the one you want to change.

So that should give you some idea of what you were asking for. It's not particularly simple, but it's a great deal of fun :-)

When you've got it all written and super-optimised, then the final step is to throw it away and just use your graphics card to do the whole thing a bazillion times faster in hardware - but let's face it, where's the fun in that? :-)

Comment: The best advice here is the first item: don't read before compare. That is, `if (p[0] == oldColor.R && p[1] == oldColor.B && p[2] == oldColor.G)`. That prevents unnecessary reads, and will likely give a measurable performance boost at minimal cost.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a project recently where I did color manipulation on a pixel per pixel basis. It had to run fast as it would update while you moved a mouse cursor around.

I started with unsafe code but I don't like unsafe code and so changed to safe territory and when I did, I had the speed issues you had but the resolution wasn't changing conditional logic. It was designing better algorithms for the pixel manipulation.

I'll give you an overview of what I did and I'm hoping it can get you where you want to be because it's really close.

First: I had multiple possible input pixel formats. Due to that I couldn't assume the RGB bytes were at specific offsets or even a static width. As such, I read the info from the passed in image and return a "color" that represents the sizes of each field:

```
    private System.Drawing.Color GetOffsets(System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat PixelFormat)
    {
        //Alpha contains bytes per color,
        // R contains R offset in bytes
        // G contains G offset in bytes
        // B contains B offset in bytes
        switch(PixelFormat)
        {
            case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb:
                return System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(3, 0, 1, 2);
            case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb:
            case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb:
                return System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(4, 1, 2, 3);
            case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb:
                return System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(4, 0, 1, 2);
            case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed:
                return System.Drawing.Color.White;
            default:
                return System.Drawing.Color.White;
        }
    }
```

For example purposes, let's say that a 24-bit RGB image is the source. I didn't want to change alpha values as I'm going to blend a color in to it.

Thus, R is at offset 0, B is at offset 1 and G at offset 2 and each pixel is three bits wide. This I create a temporary Color with this data.

Next, since this is in a custom control, I didn't want flickering so I overrode the OnPaintBackground and turned it off:

```
    protected override void OnPaintBackground(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        //base.OnPaintBackground(pevent);
    }
```

Finally, and here's the part that gets to the crux of what you're doing, I draw a new image on each OnPaint (which is triggered as a mouse moves because I "Invalidate" it in the mouse move event handler)

Full code - before I call certain sections out ...

```
    protected override void OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pe);
        pe.Graphics.FillRectangle(new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(this.BackColor), pe.ClipRectangle);
        System.Drawing.Rectangle DestinationRect = GetDestinationRectangle(pe.ClipRectangle);
        if(DestinationRect != System.Drawing.Rectangle.Empty)
        {
            System.Drawing.Image BlendedImage = (System.Drawing.Image) this.Image.Clone();
            if(HighlightRegion != System.Drawing.Rectangle.Empty && this.Image != null)
            {
                System.Drawing.Rectangle OffsetHighlightRegion = 
                    new System.Drawing.Rectangle(
                        new System.Drawing.Point(
                            Math.Min(Math.Max(HighlightRegion.X + OffsetX, 0), BlendedImage.Width - HighlightRegion.Width -1), 
                            Math.Min(Math.Max(HighlightRegion.Y + OffsetY, 0), BlendedImage.Height - HighlightRegion.Height -1)
                            )
                            , HighlightRegion.Size
                            );
                System.Drawing.Bitmap BlendedBitmap = (System.Drawing.Bitmap) BlendedImage;
                System.Drawing.Color OffsetRGB = GetOffsets(BlendedImage.PixelFormat);
                byte BlendR = SelectionColor.R;
                byte BlendG = SelectionColor.G;
                byte BlendB = SelectionColor.B;
                byte BlendBorderR = SelectionBorderColor.R;
                byte BlendBorderG = SelectionBorderColor.G;
                byte BlendBorderB = SelectionBorderColor.B;
                if(OffsetRGB != System.Drawing.Color.White) //White means not supported
                {
                    int BitWidth = OffsetRGB.G - OffsetRGB.R;
                    System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData BlendedData = BlendedBitmap.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, BlendedBitmap.Width, BlendedBitmap.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, BlendedBitmap.PixelFormat);
                    int StrideWidth = BlendedData.Stride;
                    int BytesPerColor = OffsetRGB.A;
                    int ROffset = BytesPerColor - (OffsetRGB.R + 1);
                    int GOffset = BytesPerColor - (OffsetRGB.G + 1);
                    int BOffset = BytesPerColor - (OffsetRGB.B + 1);
                    byte[] BlendedBytes = new byte[Math.Abs(StrideWidth) * BlendedData.Height];
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(BlendedData.Scan0, BlendedBytes, 0, BlendedBytes.Length);

                    //Create Highlighted Region
                    for(int Row = OffsetHighlightRegion.Top ; Row <= OffsetHighlightRegion.Bottom ; Row++)
                    {
                        for(int Column = OffsetHighlightRegion.Left ; Column <= OffsetHighlightRegion.Right ; Column++)
                        {
                            int Offset = Row * StrideWidth + Column * BytesPerColor;
                            if(Row == OffsetHighlightRegion.Top || Row == OffsetHighlightRegion.Bottom || Column == OffsetHighlightRegion.Left || Column == OffsetHighlightRegion.Right)
                            {
                                BlendedBytes[Offset + ROffset] = BlendBorderR;
                                BlendedBytes[Offset + GOffset] = BlendBorderG;
                                BlendedBytes[Offset + BOffset] = BlendBorderB;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                BlendedBytes[Offset + ROffset] = (byte) ((BlendedBytes[Offset + ROffset] + BlendR) >> 1);
                                BlendedBytes[Offset + GOffset] = (byte) ((BlendedBytes[Offset + GOffset] + BlendG) >> 1);
                                BlendedBytes[Offset + BOffset] = (byte) ((BlendedBytes[Offset + BOffset] + BlendB) >> 1);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(BlendedBytes, 0, BlendedData.Scan0, BlendedBytes.Length);
                    BlendedBitmap.UnlockBits(BlendedData);

                    //base.Image = (System.Drawing.Image) BlendedBitmap;
                }
            }
            pe.Graphics.DrawImage(BlendedImage, 0, 0, DestinationRect, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
    }
```

Going through the code here are some explanations...

```
System.Drawing.Image BlendedImage = (System.Drawing.Image) this.Image.Clone();
```

It is important to draw to an offscreen image - this creates one such image. Otherwise, the drawing will be much slower.

```
if(HighlightRegion != System.Drawing.Rectangle.Empty && this.Image != null)
```

HighlightRegion is a RECT that holds the area to "mark off" on the source image. I have used this to mark off image regions of 4 Million pixels and it still runs fast enough to be "real time"

Some code below is used because a user might be scrolled over or down on the image so I modify my destination by their scrolling amount.

Below that, I cast the IMAGE to a BITMAP and get the before-mentioned Color info which I'll need to start using now. Depending on what you're doing you might want to cache that instead of getting it each time.

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap BlendedBitmap = (System.Drawing.Bitmap) BlendedImage;
```

On my control, I exposed two Color properties - SelectionColor and SelectionBorderColor - so that my regions still have a nice border with them. Part of my speed optimization was to pre-cast these to bytes as I'll be doing bitwise operations in a moment.

You'll see a comment in the code "White not supported" - in this case, the "White" is the "Fake Color" we use to store our bit widths. I used "White" to mean "I can't operate on this data"

The next line establishes that indeed each color is one bit because they might not be depending on our target color format by subtracting the R and G offset. Note that if you cannot garauntee that your G follows your R then you'll need to use something else. In my case, it was garaunteed.

Now where the part you're really looking for starts. I use a LockBits to get the bit data. After that, I use the data to finish setting up some pre-loop variables.

And then, I copy the data to a byte array. I'm going to loop through this byte array, change the values and then copy it's data back to the BITMAP. I was working on the BITMAP directly before thinking that since it's offscreen it would be just as fast as working with a native array.

I was wrong. Performance profiling proved it to me. It's faster to copy everything to a byte array and work within that.

Now the loop starts. It goes row by row, column by column. Offset is a number telling us where in the byte array we are in terms of "current pixel".

Then, I blend 50% or I draw a border. Note that for each pixel I have not only an IF statement, but also OR checks.

And it's still fast as blazes.

Finally, I copy back and unlock the bits. And then copy the image to the onscreen surface.